# Using items in a list as dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a dictionary called 'useraccounts'. I manage to obtain all of the keys of the items in the dictionary that are in class 12 by doing:

```
found = ([k for k in useraccounts if useraccounts[k]['class'] == '12'])
```

The list returned is:

```
['bob', 'terry']
```

which is correct. Now is there anyway I could take these results as keys and then seperately use them to individually print relevant information from the dictionary. For example, get the program to print the results of:

```
useraccounts[THE_KEYS_FOUND_IN_THE_LIST]['totalscore']
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
for name in found:
    print(name, useraccounts[name]['totalscore'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build on what you had before:

```
scores = [useraccounts[k]['totalscore'] for k in useraccounts if useraccounts[k]['class'] == '12']
# scores = [ list of scores ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the totalscore for those specific keys:

```
totals = [(key,value['totalscore') for key, value in useraccounts.items() if value['class'] == '12']
```